# Delete trigger on multiple rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Below is my trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgPaxeDeleted]
   ON  [dbo].[paxe] 
   AFTER DELETE
AS 
declare
@HFflightID int,
@RFflightID int

BEGIN
        Select @HFflightID = hfFlightID, @RFflightID = rfFlightID from deleted

        -- Hinflug: flugKontingent hochsetzen --   
        UPDATE    flightdata
        SET       flightQuota = flightQuota + 1
        WHERE     (flightID = @HFflightID)

        -- Rückflug: flugKontingent hochsetzen --
        UPDATE    flightdata
        SET       flightQuota = flightQuota + 1
        WHERE     (flightID = @RFflightID)

END
```

This works fine on deleting a single row. But when deleting multiple rows only one trigger operation is done.

How do I change this?

Answer (score 10):

SQL Server triggers fire one instance of the trigger for all rows; the `deleted` table will contain all rows being updated, so you can't store a single instance in a variable.

Get rid of the following line of code:

```
Select @HFflightID = hfFlightID, @RFflightID = rfFlightID from deleted
```

Your update statment should look like this:

```
UPDATE    flightdata         
SET       flightQuota = flightQuota + 1         
WHERE     flightID IN (SELECT hfFlightID FROM deleted)

UPDATE    flightdata         
SET       flightQuota = flightQuota + 1         
WHERE     flightID IN (SELECT rfFlightID FROM deleted)
```

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I thought about an `OR` statement, but what if the `flightID` is in both `hfFlightID` and `rfFlightID`? Shouldn't it get incremented twice? I don't know if that's possible with the user's data structure.  If not, then yes, definitely merge the two statements.

Comment: When you set a scalar variable to a value from inserted or deleted, you will most likley have a trigger that can't handle multiple rows. Of course trigger testing should include multiple row  inserts/updates/deletes as well as single row tests. The worst part is it causes data integrity problems since the trigger won't fail, it will just act on one record. Eventually most tables with a trigger, in my experience, will need to import data from a file or some such. Always plan for multiple rows. And don't use a cursor or while loop to handle multiple records! That can kill database performance.

Comment: hfFlightID an rfFlightID are never same value

Comment: @user168507 can you please update your question with the exact trigger code you're using now, and is still only resulting in one row deleted, and the delete statement that caused it to fire?

Answer (score 1):

You can delete multiple rows. But you have to put multiple id. For example:

```
DELETE FROM  VisitorMaster WHERE Id=85 or Id=86
```

Answer (score 1):

I base this example and do the removal with the primary key

```
CREATE TRIGGER On_Delete 
 ON tblActivityArchive AFTER DELETE 
 AS   BEGIN 
     DELETE dbo.tblJobLinesArchive 
       FROM dbo.tblJobLinesArchive a
      INNER JOIN Deleted d ON a.ActivityRef = d.ActivityRef
END
```

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic484314-338-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The delete trigger changed to

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgPaxeDeleted]
   ON  [dbo].[paxe] 
   AFTER DELETE
AS 
declare
@HFflightID int,
@RFflightID int

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;     

    UPDATE    flightdata         
    SET       flightQuota = flightQuota + 1         
    WHERE     flightID IN (SELECT hfFlightID FROM deleted)

        UPDATE    flightdata         
    SET       flightQuota = flightQuota + 1         
    WHERE     flightID IN (SELECT rfFlightID FROM deleted)

END
```

Comment: The delete was fired by a delete trigger on another table named customers

Comment: I would check to see if the other delete trigger is improperly wirtten to only handle on row.

Comment: Even if i do a multiple delete via sql (delete from xxx where id=1 or id=2) only one trigger operation is done

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and i found an easy solution.

**First I created the Trigger Table to store deleted columns**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.XLogs (
  Field1 varchar(30),
  Field2 varchar(30),
  Field3 varchar(30),
  Field4 varchar(30),
  Field5 varchar(2)
);
```

**Then I created the trigger**

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TXLogs ON dbo.Table
AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @Id varchar(30)
   DECLARE @Field1 varchar(30)
   DECLARE @Field2 varchar(30)
   DECLARE @Field4 varchar(30)

   SELECT Id,Field1,Field2 INTO #DeletedTempTable FROM deleted

   WHILE(EXISTS(SELECT Id,Field1,Field2 FROM #DeletedTempTable))
   BEGIN
      SET @Field4 = 'Delete Row'
      SELECT TOP 1 @Id =Id , @Field1 = Field1, @Field2 = Field2 FROM #DeletedTempTable

      INSERT INTO dbo.XLogs VALUES (@Id,@Field1,@Field2,@Field4,'0')

      DELETE FROM #DeletedTempTable WHERE Id = @Id
   END
END
```

I created the temporary table to store my initial results, then loop through them using the while loop.

I selected TOP 1 to list only one row, read the data and stored it in my log table before I deleted the loop row and then loop again to get the next line. Same logic can be used for updated rows just change the FROM deleted to FROM inserted and other lines etc